# Binary tree in Java - Can't use java.collections

Tags: java, linked-list, binary-tree, export-to-csv, word-count

I need to develop a program in Java language to analyse a text file and lists the words in alphabetical order, indicating the number of occurrences of each one, its relative frequency *(number of occurrences / total number of words x 100)* and the respective lines in which it occurs as well as the total number of words.

The programme should use a binary tree as the main data structure. The lines where each word occurs will be maintained by linked lists. The program shall allow exporting the results to a file in csv format.

The problem is java collections **cannot** be used.

I'm very new to programming and I'm having a really hard time completing this project.

Comment: The problem is that you didn't ask a question. Please take the time to read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask.

Comment: Hello, please consider reading this post: [Open letter to students with homework problems](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6166) Then refer to this link: https://www.baeldung.com/java-binary-tree

Comment: Programming can be overwelmig at times. The big hint is that you need to tackle the problem one step at the time.

Start with the linked list. A binary tree is a linked list with 2 references instead of just one. And, if your data is already in alphabetical order, without a balancing strategy, your tree will just behave like a linked list. The balancing is the third problem you'll have to face.

If you don't know where to start, just get a piece of paper and a pen, and try to put down a diagam with the operations you have to deal with. Paper and pen at times like that help you focus!

Comment: @LucaScarcia I think the "in alphabetical order" refers to the output, not the input, and the question doesn't mention balancing the tree, so I would not introduce that complication.

Comment: @tgdavies reading the question, in the very first line it says that the input file lists the words in alphabetical order. It's a classic to see if you understand how a binary tree works. He will need to balance the tree. That's just how homeworks work...

Comment: @LucaScarcia I'm pretty sure that means "a program, which when given a text file, lists the words in alphabetical order". Note that each word may occur many times, in different lines of the input.

Comment: @tgdavies we will need the OP to tell us how it works. No meaning arguing about this between us.

Comment: @tgdavies "a program, which when given a text file, lists the words in alphabetical order" is exactly what i meant! I think my main problem is that i don't know where to start and since i can't use Java Collections, all of the things i look up online only confuses me more..!

Comment: @Mihe My question is "Can anyone help?"

Comment: If you google "java binary tree tutorial" there are a lot of hits. For instance https://www.baeldung.com/java-binary-tree looks ok. Of course you'll be storing a `String` in the `Node` instead of an `int`, and you don't need all the operations they show, just insert and traverse.